# Wso2 saml assertion revoke and create new

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using Wso2 SAML for authentication and XACML for authorization. After wso2 authentication, how to revoke the SAML token and generate a new token?

Comment: `And using webservice from wso2 how to validate the assertion using assertion id?` what do you mean?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Querying+SAML+Assertions using assertionId we can get the query assertion. But I am having to doubt how to refresh the assertion after certain period(I mean expiry period).

Answer (score 1):

> how to revoke the SAML token and generate a new token

Reading the question it invokes me an idea, that there is an attempt to treat the SAML Assertions similar as the JWT token (hold and use until expires, revoke or request a new one). Please don't do that. I've seen multiple developers even succeeding with builing a system that passes the SAML assertions along the other API requests. It is possible, but not intended and not always feasible. SAML Assertions document can be large, specifically when encrypting the assertions.

SAML Assertions (see, I deliberately do not use word *token* not to be mistaken) are a one-time certificate where the issuer (IdP) asserts information about the subject. There is no direct  backend connection between IdP and SP (there is no token service, this is an intended feature of SAML) and all needed information are passed in the Assertions. Then it is necessary to prevent the replay attack, so the lifetime of the SAM assertions is usually short only to allow some clock skew between the IdP and SP (5-15 minutes). It is writte  somewhere i  the [SAML specs](http://saml.xml.org/saml-specifications)

The client can/needs to establish its own use of the information in the assertion (e. g. session cookie, own jwt token, whatever) . SAML doesn't prescribe its use, only mandatory validation steps. WSO2IS offers an [SAML Bearer OAuth2 profile](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/60493984) to swap the SAML Assertion for the JWT token.

> But I am having to doubt how to refresh the assertion after certain period(I mean expiry period).

Disclaimer - I never used that profile. Based on the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/querying-saml-assertions/) the client could remember the assertion id and request the current / extended subject attributes (like a userinfo service for SAML). As comes from my experience, it's better to pass all required information in the original SAML assertion and not to use any very volatile attributes as an identity attribute.

Comment: but how we can refresh assertion as it'll have certain period or it'll automatically get extended by wso2

Comment: @rahul `it'll automatically get extended` No idea. In that time you could test it, find out and let us know. `we can refresh assertion` as I said there is no *refresh* concept defined in SAML. The assertion is not mean to be refreshed